# ASP.net - foreach two children in a parent div

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I tried to `foreach` my `itemList`, two child items in one parent div. I also tried to use `index` with `index++` to check number of child items, in order to add to parent html. However it is not right.

```
var index = 1;
@foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    if (index % 2 == 0){
        <div class="parent-item">
    }
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    if (index % 2 == 0){
        </div>
    }
    index++;
}
```

Below is expected result:

```
<div class="parent-item">
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    <div class="child-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the content of `itemList`? Is it three items - one parent followed by two children? Or one parent item that _contains_ two children?

Comment: @DStanley it just a list of object , i just wish to group them two by two in a parent , so let say if the list have 10 object , so it just foreach 5 parent div , contain 2 children div each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your root problem is that you're outputting the "parent" start and end tags around the even items since you're checking for `index % 2 == 0` in both cases.

Also, rather then a `foreach` that keeps track of the index, you can do a `for`, and check for the "last" item in case there is an odd number of items:

```
@for (int index=0; index < itemList.Count(); index++)
{
    item = itemList[index];
    if (index % 2 == 0){
        @:<div class="parent-item">
    }
    <div class="child-item"></div>
    if (index % 2 == 1 || index == (itemList.Count() - 1)){
        @:</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: i get an error from visual studio, `Encountered end tag "div" with no matching start tag. Are your start/end tags properly balanced?`

Comment: the last part i have to add @ razor symbol in order the let the code know is using razor, so it came up the end tag error `@if (index % 2 == 1 || index == (itemList.Count() - 1)){ </div> }`

Comment: @FeelRightz I added `@:` to treat those as literals rather then tags to get rid of that error.

Comment: omg , thank you so much , this is it , the answer that i want